# How to use a PowerShell script to run another PowerShell Script on a Remote Computer

Tags: windows, powershell

I am looking to keep all the computers on my network up to date with the Defender Anti-Virus definitions by setting up a PowerShell script that will automatically download them from the Microsoft website. The script will then transfer the the .exe file from my computer to all the computers in a text file.

What I want it to do now is to run the .exe on the remote computer but I am not getting it to work somehow. Below is my code.

```cs
$File = "https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=121721&arch=x64"
$Location = "C:\temp\mpam-fe.exe"
$Client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$Client.DownloadFile($File, $Location)

Write-Host "Downloading file..."

$Computers = Get-Content "C:\temp\Computers.txt"

foreach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    $Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
    Copy-Item -Path C:\temp\mpam-fe.exe C:\temp\ -ToSession $Session -Recurse -Force
    Write-Host "Transferring file to $Computer"
    Enter-PSSession $Computer
    Set-Location "C:\temp\"
    Invoke-Command ./RunAV.ps1
    Exit-PSSession
}
```

The error message that I receive when it tries to run the script on the remote computer

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named
parameters.
At C:\PSScripts\AVDownload.ps1:16 char:9
+         Invoke-Command ./RunAV.ps1
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` and `Exit-PSSession` are for interactive use. Don't use them in non-interactive contexts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the script you want to run appears to be located on the remote computer you should run it like this:

```
$Session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
Copy-Item ...
Invoke-Command -Session $Session -Scriptblock {
    Set-Location 'C:\temp'
    & ./RunAV.ps1
}
```